# How to properly run all Junit tests in Spring without a db connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

Hi friends hope you are doing well.

So I was writing some simple unit tests for my simple project and I as soon as started to run the tests, I faced some problem.

*First of all there are the tests code :*

**GetAllUsersServiceTest.java**

```
package com.challenge.simpleApi.domains.users.services.getAllUsersService;

import com.challenge.simpleApi.domains.users.models.Users;
import com.challenge.simpleApi.domains.users.repositories.UsersRepository;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class GetAllUsersServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private UsersRepository usersRepository;

  @InjectMocks
  private GetAllUsersService getAllUsersService;

  private List<Users> fakeRepositoryReturn = new ArrayList<Users>();
  final Users user1 = new Users(1L, "John", 28, null);
  final Users user2 = new Users(2L, "Peter", 20, null);
  final Users user3 = new Users(3L, "Patricia", 21, null);

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    fakeRepositoryReturn.add(user1);
    fakeRepositoryReturn.add(user2);
    fakeRepositoryReturn.add(user3);
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Should be able to return all Users")
  void ShouldReturnAllUsers() {
    Mockito.when(usersRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(fakeRepositoryReturn);
    List<Users> actual = getAllUsersService.execute();
    Assertions.assertEquals(fakeRepositoryReturn, actual);
  }
}
```

**CreateUsersServiceTest.java**

```
package com.challenge.simpleApi.domains.users.services.CreateUsersService;

import com.challenge.simpleApi.domains.users.models.Users;
import com.challenge.simpleApi.domains.users.repositories.UsersRepository;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;

//@SpringBootTest
//@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CreateUsersServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private UsersRepository usersRepository;

  @InjectMocks
  private CreateUsersService createUsersService;

  //Validator Instances - Used to validate the annotations inside the entities
  private static ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;
  private static Validator validator;

 @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {}

  @BeforeAll
  static void beforeAll() {
    //Instantiate the validators
    validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
  }

  @AfterAll
  static void afterAll() {
    validatorFactory.close();
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Should be able to create a new User")
  void createUserTest() {
    Users userInput = new Users(null, "Jonas", 28, null);
    Users expected = new Users(1L, "Jonas", 28, null);
    Mockito.when(usersRepository.save(userInput)).thenReturn(expected);
    Users actual = createUsersService.execute(userInput);
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Should not be able to create a new User without a name")
  void CreateUserWithoutNameTet() {
    Users userInput = new Users(null, null, 18, null);
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Users>> violations = validator.validate(userInput);
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    errors =
      violations.stream().map(x -> x.getMessage()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    Assertions.assertEquals("Name should not be empty", errors.get(0));
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Should not be able to create a new under 18yo User")
  void CreateUnder18User() {
    Users userInput = new Users(null, "Paull", 17, null);
    var errors = validator
      .validate(userInput)
      .stream()
      .map(x -> x.getMessage())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Assertions.assertEquals("Should not be less than 18", errors.get(0));
  }
}
```

As you noticed, my unit tests don't need an database to run(To be honest it doesn't make any sense to have it at all) I even mocked the repository. When I run them individually, they run pretty good

```
mvn test -Dtest=GetAllUsersServiceTest
mvn test -Dtest=CreateUsersServiceTest
```

However When I run them all, my tests get messed up :

```
mvn test
```

And it looks like it's trying to connect to a database. Honestly I couldn't find how can I change this behavior. They run pretty good individually, however when I run them all ta once, things start to be strange.

If you guys could help me understand what's going wrong, I Would be thankfull

Thanks in advance

**Here is the error stack :**

```
2021-01-31 14:18:45.328  INFO 17704 --- [           main] c.c.simpleApi.SimpleApiApplicationTests  : Starting SimpleApiApplicationTests using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-AO5BOC0 with PID 17704 (started by matt in /home/matt/Source/java/simpleApi)
2021-01-31 14:18:45.333  INFO 17704 --- [           main] c.c.simpleApi.SimpleApiApplicationTests  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-31 14:18:46.114  INFO 17704 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-01-31 14:18:46.158  INFO 17704 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 38 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-01-31 14:18:46.689  INFO 17704 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-01-31 14:18:46.724  INFO 17704 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
2021-01-31 14:18:46.752  INFO 17704 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-01-31 14:18:46.827  INFO 17704 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-31 14:18:47.877 ERROR 17704 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

[...]

        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        ... 135 common frames omitted

2021-01-31 14:18:47.929  WARN 17704 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

[...] 

        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
        ... 118 common frames omitted

2021-01-31 14:18:47.981 ERROR 17704 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@a6a66fac] to prepare test instance [com.challenge.simpleApi.SimpleApiApplicationTests@a25870b7]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

[...]

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.376 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.challenge.simpleApi.SimpleApiApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   SimpleApiApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Applicati...
[ERROR]   CreateUsersServiceTest.CreateUnder18User:71 NullPointer Cannot invoke "javax.v...
[ERROR]   CreateUsersServiceTest.CreateUserWithoutNameTet:56 NullPointer Cannot invoke "...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

**EDIT: POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.challenge</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simpleApi</name>
    <description>A simple api made crafted with spring</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.16</org.projectlombok.version>
    <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>15</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
          <target>15</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: That's a good question, I'm also curious... But anyway, you can always mock a connection using `testcontainers`...

Comment: @k-wasilewski Hi friend,thanks for the tip. I was also reading about testcontainers, they seem powerful, but in this specific case they are like an "overkill" aren't they?Thanks :)

Comment: What junit version do you use in pom.xml?

Comment: Try adding this to each of your test classes @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

Comment: @Alien I'm using the JUnit integrated to SpringBoot, I added the whole POM.XML. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @mark Thanks for the tip, I've tried but still the same problem :/

Comment: ok. sorry, it did not work. Hope you tried this too ! @DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

Comment: if we look at the logs, this particular test class `SimpleApiApplicationTests` is trying to connect with database, looks like that is integration test case @MattV

Comment: @Deadpool Oh my God! You are right, there was a default class created by spring initializr trying to test everything. Man how I didn't see it. Thank you very much, I was trying to understand it for hours. Post it as an reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is originally posted by @deadpool in the comments.

Spring Initializr creates an example test class in the test package. This class has the **@SpringBootTest** annotation.

This annotation ensures a complete Spring boot environment is loaded within the test, requiring a connection.

The solution to this case is remove the annotation, or remove the java file itself.